# Check if all elements of ListA exists in ListB using python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```
ListA = [1,9,6,3,2,4]

ListB = range(min(ListA),(max(ListA)+1))
i.e ListB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I want to check if all elements of ListA exists in ListB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `issubset` to achieve that (I prefer to rename your variables to make them more pythonic):

```
l1 = [1, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4]
l2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> set(l1).issubset(set(l2))
True
```

You may also use `issuperset` as follows:

```
>>> set(l2).issuperset(set(l1))
True
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) to check `ListA` is subset of `ListB` as:

```
>>> ListA = [1, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4]
>>> ListB = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>> set(ListA) <= set(ListB)  # OR, using `set(ListA).issubset(set(ListB))`
True
```

OR, you may use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to check that iteratively:

```
# Iterates over ListA and checks each item is in ListB
>>> all(item in ListB for item in ListA)
True
```

Comment: You can see ListA dont have elements 5,7,8.  Then how can all elements of B are in A?

Comment: As my comment says it *"Iterates over ListA and checks each item is in ListB"*. What you just mentioned is opposite of what my code does.

Comment: Yes moinuddin, I want to check if all element of A exist in B,print "Yes" else "No", but with above solution list A dont have elements 5,7,8 of list B. So it should be "No"/ False

Comment: In that case what you want is not what you asked for. Because, *all element of a*, are `[1, 9, 6, 3, 2, 4]` and all these elements are present in *b*.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Are you sure? Have you tried it? Check this refrence: https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/types-set.html specially the table

Comment: Sorry, I checked with the same size list with the same contents and it failed. I made the wrong assumption. Still it should be <=, otherwise it fails if all of the elements are the same.

Comment: `=` means whether you want the complete set to be part of sub-set, or just want to check of subset. Indeed I want the complete set match, updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with subsets.

`set(ListA).issubset(set(ListB))`